# Font Awesome 6 caret not showing

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a select box in which I want a [Font Awesome 6 caret](https://fontawesome.com/icons/caret-down?f=classic&s=solid) to show.

I now have this code, but the caret does not show, even thought Font Awesome 6 is successfully loaded on the site. [See it live here](https://www.zomoa.com/product/mens-ring-vanguard-with-mystic-symbols/). Why is it not showing?

PS. I want to to do this via pure CSS and not via changing the HTML structure of the `select` element so it applies everywhere.

```
    <div class="avada-select-parent">
        <select id="pa_ring-size" class="" name="attribute_pa_ring-size" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_ring-size" data-show_option_none="yes">
            <option value="">Choose an option</option>
            <option value="14" class="attached enabled">14</option>
            <option value="14-5" class="attached enabled">14.5</option>
        </select>
        <div class="select-arrow" style="height: 38.4px; width: 38.4px; line-height: 38.4px;"></div>
    </div>
```

```css
    /* Style for the select box */
    #pa_ring-size {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 10px 40px 10px 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      font-size: 16px;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    /* Style for the select arrow using ::after pseudo-element */
    #pa_ring-size::after {
      content: '\f0d7'; 
      font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Pro';
      font-weight: 900; 
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      pointer-events: none;
    }

    .avada-select-parent {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: The HTML already contains a select arrow, so why are you wanting to add another one using a pseudo-element?

Comment: @BrettDonald thank. It seems to be autogenerated by WordPress, it is not visible anyway so am just ignoring it. And it does not achieve my desired design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select:after` - does not work.
You have a separate block for the arrow, so style it:

```css
.avada-select-parent {
  --height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#pa_ring-size {
  --padding:10px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: var(--height);
  padding: 0 calc(var(--height) + var(--padding)) 0 var(--padding);
}

.select-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 auto;
  width: var(--height);
  display: grid!important;
  place-items: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 0!important;
  color: black!important;
}

.select-arrow:before {
  content: "\f0d7";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="avada-select-parent">
  <select id="pa_ring-size" class="" name="attribute_pa_ring-size" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_ring-size" data-show_option_none="yes">
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="14" class="attached enabled">14</option>
    <option value="14-5" class="attached enabled">14.5</option>
  </select>
  <div class="select-arrow" style="height: 38.4px; width: 38.4px; line-height: 38.4px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. As you can see in my instructions, I can't edit the HTML as it's generated by wordpress, so I need to work with the HTML I provided in my original post.. I added your exact code, as you can see on my live site, but still I don't see the icon.

Comment: Ok, I understand you and updated the answer using your original html.

Comment: You do not have a font connected. In addition, the color of the arrow is transparent. Connect font using `@font-face{
font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Free';
font-display: swap;
src: url('https://www.zomoa.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/assets/fonts/fontawesome/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2');
font-weight: 900;
}`. Or added in head `<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
`. And copy my css again, I've tweaked it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it might be a font family issue.

```
/* Style for the select box */
#pa_ring-size {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Style for the select arrow using ::after pseudo-element */
#pa_ring-size::after {
  content: '\f0d7';  /* Font Awesome icon code for caret */
  font-family: 'fas';  /* Assuming you're using the free version */
  font-weight: 900; 
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.avada-select-parent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Your solution has the same font family as I already have? I tried adding your code to check, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I've updated the answer, check the code now

Comment: Hi, still nothing is visible. Also I want to use Font Awesome 6, which seems to be missing from your code?

Comment: actually, i got your issue. check the edited code

Comment: Thanks. I use the paid version. I tried both your code as well as using `Font Awesome 6 Pro` as font-family, but still no carrot. You can actually see and test this on the website link I provided above

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have installed `Fontawesome 6` correctly? Because it isn't working. . I tried using Fontawesome 5 Free and it is working fine.

Just add the following code to this file (or add the code through Custom CSS option of the theme) -> https://www.zomoa.com/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/style.css?ver=6.4.3

```
.select-arrow:after {
        color: black;
        content: '\f0d7';
        font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
        font-weight: 900;
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        pointer-events: none;
}
```

**Update**:

You definitely haven't installed 'Fontawesome 6" correctly. The icon at [zomoa.com/faq](https://zomoa.com/faq/) is not from your `Fontawesome 6 Pro`, it is likely from the local version used by Avada. I tried using the `fontawesome 6.5.1 Free` script from here- https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome and it worked fine.

**To check it out-**

You have to add the following stylesheet to the `<head>` of your document ([How to](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp))-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Then add the following code to this file (or add the code through Custom CSS option of the theme) -> https://www.zomoa.com/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/style.css?ver=6.4.3

```
.select-arrow:after {
        color: black;
        content: '\f0d7';
        font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Free';
        font-weight: 900;
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        pointer-events: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, check this page: https://www.zomoa.com/faq/, it has a font-awesome logo that I believe is only available in the Font Awesome 6 Pro library.

Comment: @Adam My browser was caching the `Fontawesome 5` so I was wrong about that part. So, you have to install Fontawesome correctly first. I have updated the answer again. Try again. You have to add the Fontawesome stylesheet to `<head>` if you couldn't get it to work through Avada.

Comment: Apparently FA6 is not directly supported by Avada. I'm reverting to FA5 as per your example and now it works with your code. Thanks!

Comment: @Adam Glad it worked, but... you have marked another answer as accepted and gave him the bounty too. Was it a mistake or do you find the other answer more helpful?

Comment: @Akshay Your answer is almost identical to mine and was given later.

Comment: @imhvost  Not really. Check edit history. You had wrote `class` based answer, while I had wrote pure CSS, which is what op wanted. Also, I had added black color, because the icon was transparent, which you added later. Op is now using the exact code I had written on my very first edit.

Comment: @Adam could tell why he didn't tried it.

Comment: The basis of the answer is that `:after` does not work on the `<select>` element. Everything else is technical trifles.

Comment: @imhvost Except, your answer never worked for op and still doesn't, while mine was working, worked and has been used exactly as it is.

Answer (score -1):

why didn't you use this method?

```
<option value="14" class="attached enabled">14 <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></option>
```